# Cliping a background layout in Android

Tags: android, clip

I am trying to get below image background design in XML but not succeeded.

[image]

My code are as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/bright_sky_blue_95"
        android:startColor="@color/light_indigo_95"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="100dp" />

</shape>
```

Any idea or example would be great. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the colours as per your need.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="302"
        android:viewportHeight="472">
        <path android:pathData="M0,122.9c0,108.3 0.2,123 1.5,123.5 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.5,0.5 2,0.4 1.6,-0.4 -0.4,-0.6 -0.2,-1.1 0.3,-1.1 0.8,-0 1.1,-23.5 1.1,-77l0,-77 -151,-0 -151,-0 0,122.9z">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:endX="360"
                    android:endY="208"
                    android:startX="0"
                    android:startY="0"
                    android:tileMode="repeat"
                    android:type="linear">
                    <item
                        android:color="#1976d2"
                        android:offset="0" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#EF5350"
                        android:offset="0.5" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </vector>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. Almost achieved. but there is an edge at the bottom line which is clearly visible. see the following picture,.https://imgur.com/ymI421p